# Automated Website Testing using GUI

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

What is the best way for automated front-end testing using GUI for a WebSite?

I have to write testing module to test whole website automatically using GUI whatever a user can do on website.

I have used mocha for testing the code but it does not provide GUI.

Comment: are you looking for a GUI based automated testing tool which can be used to automate your website testing? I am not sure if I got your question correctly.

Answer (score 9):

It's worth to take a look on Selenium Webdriver.

This framework is one of the most popular for functional testing of web-applications.

Here are the most notable features of Webdriver:

- Direct calls to browser API
- A lot of supported browsers
- Opportunity to develop automated tests using different programming languages: Java, C#, Python and other
- Ability to execute tests in "headless" mode
- Mature and efficient webdriver's API allowing you to handle many like alerts, AJAX interactions, file upload and other

You'll also find that a lot of 3rd party applications and services (like browserstack) have tight integration with Selenium Webdriver and ready to integrate with it out of the box.

Last but not least is Selenium Webdriver's community: it's huge and professional, allowing you to get answers quickly.

You can find more information about Webdriver on official [web-site](http://seleniumhq.org), and also browse [blogs](http://it-kosmopolit.de/Selenium/blog/selenium-blogs/selenium_blogs.php) related to it.

Answer (score 3):

As Viktor has noted, [Selenium Webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) is usually the tool to go to.
In my experience, it is best to not use Selenium directly, but through a wrapper. Those wrappers take care of tedious timing issues that come with the asynchronicity of the web. Good wrappers are:

- [WebdriverJS](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) (Javascript)
- [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) (Ruby) and
- [Coypu](https://github.com/featurist/coypu) (C#)

Most wrappers have the additonal benefit of making it easy to replace the selenium webdriver with others (e.g. Watir or Watin), if the need should ever arise.

WebdriverJS works [well](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Writing_Tests) with Mocha, but if you are working with Angular you might take a look at [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor), which ties all the tools well together.

For performance reasons and easy deployment on test machines you should take a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), a headless browser based on Webkit.

**Update:** Pareshkumar's comment made me think. If you are looking for a GUI to launch the tests from, instead of a way to test the GUI of your website, the search term you are looking for ist **testrunner**. [Testem](https://github.com/airportyh/testem) for example is a testrunner, that has both a cli and a gui. You should definitely look for cli support to enable continuous integration.

Comment: +1 for you @Jörg Reichardt since wrappers are also sometimes handy. Of course depending on tasks and environment/platform you want to test at.

Answer (score 0):

Very good option can be usage of python based robot framework with selenium server/webdriver.

**What you need:**

Python 2.7 installation

Robotframework (latest stable version)

- Comes with: [set of standard libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/#standard-libraries)
- To test GUI install -  [selenium library](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-seleniumlibrary/) ([selenium2library[3](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/#readme) optional)

Selenium server

Robotframework act as a test runner and result collector. Selenium library connect robotframework with selenium server (or webdriver).

To write test cases, there is good IDE - RIDE.

- install wxPython 2.8
- install [robotframework-ride](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE)

Robotframework is very good tool for testing GUI part of application, but with custom third party libraries, you can test various scenarios - databases, http, soap, and so on.

For further documentation visit - [robotframework.org](http://robotframework.org/)